# Passing arguments in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, parameter-passing, jupyter-notebook

Im following the book "Learn Python The Hard Way", and i'm at exc13. 
The excercice is as follow:

```
from sys import argv
# read the WYSS section for how to run this
script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

But when I run this i got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b23ff5448130> in <module>()
      1 from sys import argv
      2 # read the WYSS section for how to run this
----> 3 script, first, second, third = argv
      4 
      5 print("The script is called:", script)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

This is because argv isnt filled. The book says to use a terminal, in the terminal you can pass the arguments by typing:

```
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

in the terminal. But how can i do this only using the Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Jupyter Notebook, you can create a file using the cell magic `%%file`.  You can then send a command to the shell to run the file using the cell magic `%%!`.

To write out the file:

```
%%file ex13.py
from sys import argv
# read the WYSS section for how to run this
script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

To run the file:

```
%%!
python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
```

You should see the results you are looking for.  The printed output is captured and returned as a list, one element per printed line.